# Function to find if a date exists and if so print that row of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to create a function that takes in a date and scans the DF for this date in a date column, the date column is in datetime format. Once it finds the date I want it to return the matching orders row from the dataframe: I have managed to make a start on this like so, but I cant get the return I want:

e.g DF

````
          date     orders
5351660 2020-08-03  1011
5351719 2020-08-04  1012
5812943 2020-08-05  1013
5814499 2020-08-06  2565
5350549 2020-08-07  5555
5350484 2020-08-08  2546
5813992 2020-08-09  8945
5351067 2020-08-10  6965
5350968 2020-08-11  1236```



```def weekoforders(date):
    x = df1['date'].eq(date).any() else 'no'
    return df1[df1['orders'] == x]

weekoforders('2020-08-07')
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    cond=df['date'].isin([pd.to_datetime(date)])
    if cond.any():
        return df.loc[cond,'orders']
    return 'No'

weekoforders('2021-08-07')
```